# Building network in R

Tags: r, csv, igraph, vertices, edges

I have a csv file which looks like this:

```
"","people_id","commit_id"
 "1",1,0
 "2",1,117
 "3",1,144
 "4",1,278
 …
```

[Here's](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2nh7hs30kjk3092/commits.csv?dl=0) the csv file if you wanna look at it. It contains 11735 lines but 5923 unique people ids.

Does anyone know how to connect the people ids with the common "commit_id" and ignore commit_id 0 as id 0 does not exist.

For now I have done this:

```
# read the csv file 
commitsNetwork <- read.csv("commits.csv", header=TRUE)

# use a subset for demo purpose

commitsNetwork <- commitsNetwork[c("people_id", "commit_id")]

#build edgelist(for commits)
C <- spMatrix(nrow = length(unique(commitsNetwork$people_id)),
              ncol = length(unique(commitsNetwork$commit_id)),
              i = as.numeric(factor(commitsNetwork$people_id)),
              j = as.numeric(factor(commitsNetwork$commit_id)),
              x = rep(1, length(as.numeric(commitsNetwork$people_id))) )
row.names(C) <- levels(factor(commitsNetwork$people_id))
colnames(C) <- levels(factor(commitsNetwork$commit_id))
adjC <- tcrossprod(C) 
comG <- graph.adjacency(adjC, mode = "undirected", weighted = TRUE, diag = FALSE)

#write to pajek file
write.graph(comG, "comNetwork.net", format = "pajek")
```

Also, the edges are from the 2nd column "commit_id". If both vertices(people) are connected by the common commit_id from the 6th column.

Therefore I'm not sure how to generate the network with this csv file in R.

The ideal output is should turn out like:

*Vertices 5923
1

2

3

4

...

*Edges

1 4 1

1 25 1

1 39 1

1 41 1

1 48 1

until 5923...

Comment: You can do e.g. `vcount(people.network); ecount(people.network); head(V(people.network))`. How do you want the network, i.e. what's the source, what's the target of a node? Right now, it's people<-->comitters.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That i know but right now my data has duplication of people ids and i just want the unique ids for the vertices.  I want the network to be like people(vertices) and the edges are the repository_id. two people are connected by the common repository id  @lukeA

Comment: `people[!duplicated(people$people), ]` has no duplicates of the people column in the original data frame. So, in theory, you just need the peple and the repository_id column?

Comment: yes that's right. how do i do so? @lukeA

Comment: Also, but if you look carefully at the people ids, the reason why they have duplicate ids are because one person can have many repository ids belong to. Thats why it's important to just take note of the unique values(1-5923) and the repo id where it belongs. @lukeA

Comment: If I understood correctly you want a network where repo ids are edges and people are nodes, right? Take a look at my answer (too much for a comment.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you want something like this:

```
library(igraph)
library(Matrix)

download.file("https://www.dropbox.com/s/q7sxfwjec97qzcy/people.csv?dl=1", 
              tf <- tempfile(fileext = ".csv"), mode = "wb")
people <- read.csv(tf)

A <- spMatrix(nrow = length(unique(people$people)),
              ncol = length(unique(people$repository_id)),
              i = as.numeric(factor(people$people)),
              j = as.numeric(factor(people$repository_id)),
              x = rep(1, length(as.numeric(people$people))) )
row.names(A) <- levels(factor(people$people))
colnames(A) <- levels(factor(people$repository_id))
adj <- tcrossprod(A) 
g <- graph.adjacency(adj, mode = "undirected", weighted = TRUE, diag = FALSE)
```

See also [here](https://solomonmessing.wordpress.com/2012/09/30/working-with-bipartiteaffiliation-network-data-in-r/).

Comment: Can you explain how you build edgelist and graph from it? Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: I connected each people with each people within a repo id and labeled the edge with the repo id. This is only a subset of repo ids 1 and 2. I wonder if that's really what you want...

Comment: So for example, 2 and 4 are connected based on the same repo id? If so, yes that's what I wanted. can you explain the l and d variable statements? I don't understand what you're trying to do there. Thank you so much for your help. :)

Comment: #1: There is are two rows in people with member==2 and member==4, where each has repository_id = 1. In the graph, 2 and 4 are connected by repo id 1 (curved edge, which should habe no arrow -> `g <- graph.data.frame(d, directed = F)`).  #2: Have a look at `?combn` (l statement). #3: This just merges the list elements to one data frame with label preserving the repo ids as edge labels.

Comment: @user101 If it's what you needed, you can check the answer and mark the topic as solved.

Comment: Hey, I've edited your codes but I'm not sure how to build edge list and graph from it.

Comment: So far, I've got this: people <- people[c("people", "repository_id")]

Comment: It's all in the example code above. Of course, it'll take a long time to calculate though...

Comment: Ok, that's because some repo ids have only one people. If you want to exclude those, try `l <- lapply(split(people$people, people$repository_id), function(x) if (length(x) > 1) t(combn(x, 2))); l <- l[sapply(l, length) > 0]` instead of the `l` line above.

Comment: There seems to have a fatal error when plotting the graph. Do you know why?

Comment: Because it's too big? I don't know, because I wouldn't plot it using R. Export it to gephi and try again: http://gephi.github.io/

Comment: May i know why did you transpose the data frame "t(combn(x, 2))"?

Comment: Because otherwise it would have a wide shape. Check e.g. with `...  function(x) { browser(); t(combn(x, 2))  })` -> try entering `x`, `combn(x, 2)` and `t(combn(x, 2))` in browser mode.

Comment: it seems that the edges is wrong as some people that does not have the common repo is still written down. I have checked this by writing it to a Pajek file. I have edited the ideal output in my question.

Comment: Can you name an example edge?

Comment: Edge is where the two vertices that are connected by the common repository id. Example if people id 1 and people id 2 has the common repository_id then it will be connected together

Comment: Thus, in pajek file it will write down the edges as follows in the question I edited. The 3rd column of the edges is the weight where it count how many common repositories these two vertices have

Comment: Ah so you want an edge not to be a repository but the NUMBER of repositories?

Comment: The two people ids who does not have the common repository_id is also being connected together.

Comment: Pardon me. The edge is the relationship between two people who has the common repository id and the WEIGHT is the number of repositories each pair has the common repositories. This is basically the concept of edge in [social network analysis](http://mrvar.fdv.uni-lj.si/sola/info4/uvod/part1.pdf)

Comment: Yes, _"the edges are from the 6th column "repository_id". If both vertices(people) are connected by the common repository_id from the 6th column."_ was a bit misleading to me and - to be honest - the graph made no sense to me, but that doesn't mean it doesn't make sense to anyone else. ;)

Comment: See my edit. Now, the edges should have source, target and weight (= number of common repository ids)

Comment: Thanks for the help. But the output that i get shows that the target are in sequence(means going from 2-5923) thus affecting that people id 1 and people id 10 are connected which shouldnt be because they does not have the common repo id.

Comment: Also, may i know what is this source and target?

Comment: An edge is a connection between two nodes - Source is one, target is the other. I made an edit with regards to this nice post: https://solomonmessing.wordpress.com/2012/09/30/working-with-bipartiteaffiliation-network-data-in-r/

Comment: Learned sth myself, so it was worth it. :)

Comment: I have another question. I have another file which similar to "people.csv" but in this case, they connected the two vertices with repo id 0 which (repo id 0 does not exist). How do i fix this? I've edited my question.

Comment: It has no problem with "people.csv" and they didn't connect the people with repo id 0. I see why there's a problem with new csv file "commit.csv"